# How to exclude multiple values from JSON String in MS SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, json

I am having a JSON string like below:

```
{
  "Country": {
    "Layer4": [
      {
        "ItemName": "Cabinet MT",
        "ItemId": "cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414"
      },
      {
        "ItemName": "Other MT",
        "ItemId": "cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414"
      },
      {
        "ItemName": "Cold MT",
        "ItemId": "cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414"
      },
      {
        "ItemName": "Cold MT",
        "ItemId": "672f9a8c-71bb-4851-87de-e68154cabfad"
      },
      {
        "ItemName": "Cabinet MT",
        "ItemId": "672f9a8c-71bb-4851-87de-e68154cabfad"
      }
    ]
  },
  "CountryID": "b4283692-7c14-46da-9480-9a2976187316"
}
```

I want to remove data under Layer4 whose `ItemName = 'Cabinet MT' and ItemName = 'Other MT' and ItemId = 'cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414'` and finally I want JSON string to look like this:

```
{
  "Country": {
    "Layer4": [
      {
        "ItemName": "Cold MT",
        "ItemId": "cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414"
      },
      {
        "ItemName": "Cold MT",
        "ItemId": "672f9a8c-71bb-4851-87de-e68154cabfad"
      },
      {
        "ItemName": "Cabinet MT",
        "ItemId": "672f9a8c-71bb-4851-87de-e68154cabfad"
      }
    ]
  },
  "CountryID": "b4283692-7c14-46da-9480-9a2976187316"
}
```

I have tried in below format:

```
Declare @Input NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{"Country":{"Layer4":[{"ItemName":"Cabinet MT","ItemId":"cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414"},{"ItemName":"Other MT","ItemId":"cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414"},{"ItemName":"Cold MT","ItemId":"cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414"},{"ItemName":"Cold MT","ItemId":"672f9a8c-71bb-4851-87de-e68154cabfad"},{"ItemName":"Cabinet MT","ItemId":"672f9a8c-71bb-4851-87de-e68154cabfad"}]},"CountryID":"b4283692-7c14-46da-9480-9a2976187316"}';
DECLARE @JSONOutput AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @JSONData AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @JSONData = @Input; 

            SELECT @JSONOutput = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONData, '$.Country.Layer4', JSON_QUERY('[]'))
            SELECT @JSONOutput = JSON_MODIFY(@JSONOutput, 'append $.Country.Layer4', JSON_QUERY(@JSONData, '$.Country.Layer4[' + [key] + ']'))
            FROM OPENJSON(@JSONData, '$.Country.Layer4')
            WHERE JSON_VALUE([value], '$.ItemName') NOT IN('Cabinet MT', 'Other MT')
            and JSON_VALUE([value], '$.ItemId') NOT IN ('cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414')

            Print @JSONOutput
```

and I am getting output as:

```
{
  "Country": {
    "Layer4": [
      {
        "ItemName": "Cold MT",
        "ItemId": "672f9a8c-71bb-4851-87de-e68154cabfad"
      }
    ]
  },
  "CountryID": "b4283692-7c14-46da-9480-9a2976187316"
}
```

Could some one help me to remove only specific values which satisfy my condition

Comment: Why have you tagged both SQL Server *and* MySQL? What RDBMS are you really using? What does the above have to do with C# when there's no C# code in the above and it's never mentioned? What do Stored Procedures have to do with the problem as well? I've removed basically all the tags here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag things appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a wrong boolean logic, try to use a different `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE NOT (
   (JSON_VALUE([value], '$.ItemName') = N'Other MT') AND (JSON_VALUE([value], '$.ItemId') = N'cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414') OR
   (JSON_VALUE([value], '$.ItemName') = N'Cabinet MT') AND (JSON_VALUE([value], '$.ItemId') = N'cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414')
)
```

An important note (as is explained in the [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks)): *Don't use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) aren't necessarily run exactly once for each output row.*

A possible approach is to parse, filter and rebuild the input JSON:

```
SELECT @JSONOutput = JSON_MODIFY (
   @Input,
   '$.Country.Layer4',
   (
   SELECT * 
   FROM OPENJSON(@Input, '$.Country.Layer4') WITH (
      ItemName nvarchar(100) '$.ItemName',
      ItemId nvarchar(36) '$.ItemId'
   )  
   WHERE NOT (
      (ItemName = N'Other MT') AND (ItemId = N'cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414') OR
      (ItemName = N'Cabinet MT') AND (ItemId = N'cc3b0435-9ff5-4fd8-9f49-e049919a1414')
   )  
   FOR JSON PATH
   )
)
```

Comment: Here I am having only 2 properties in myJSON Input i.e; ItemId and ItemName but If I have more no of properties like ItemDiscount,ItemPlace,etc, it is difficult to write every property inside my query like With(ItemName nvarchar(100) '$.ItemName',  ItemId nvarchar(36),$.ItemId',$.ItemDiscount  nvarchar(100) '$.ItemDiscount, $.ItemPrice nvarchar(100) '$.ItemPrice)..If there is any other alternative to reduce this syntax would help in maintainence